# Overwrite file content with variable data

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, client-side

Using jquery open file (e.q. test.txt), and replace it with data written in your variable. Is it possible.

```
var text_variable = "Some text";
```

Now open file e.q. test.txt and clear all content and replace it with text_variable.

Comment: You can only do this if you utilize a server-side language such as PHP, Node.js, .NET, etc.

Comment: javascript(and jquery) will only work on the client machine. to alter files on server see Chen's comment above. if you need to store stuff on client's machine, you better off using cookies or local storage or something. dont mess around with files as browsers are not too keen on allowing you access client's filesystem due to security reasons.

Comment: And with PHP/.net or every other Server-Side-Language you are able to write Files on the Server, not on the Client.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write text files with Javascript for security reasons.

Comment: Is there a way to save automatically file in folder "tmp" using variable data, without asking user to choose loaction and set name (Save as..).

Comment: @josaric it is decided by the browser and unless you write a browser extension, this is impossible.

Comment: No. If that would be easy to write useless code on every client that comes to my webpage. You could create a Java Applet or something like that - then (if the user allows this to be executed) a file could be written on every directory on the client computer

Answer (score -1):

You cant write to a text file.  You can write to localStorage.

```
var text_variable = "Some text";
localStorage.setKey('myText', text_variable);

//later in the code
var t2 = localStorage.geyKey('myText');  
console.log(t2);  // outputs   Some Text
```